# Como fazer validação de data?

Tags: java, android

Como efetuar a validação de data como a data de nascimento? Não podendo colocar a data no futuro.

```
        data.addTextChangedListener(DateUtils.insert("##/##/####", data));


                 mData = data.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Você já tentou algo?

Comment: Não entendi. Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Na minha tela de cadastro o usuario vai colocar a data de nascimento,eu vou passar o texto escrito para string,a data que o usuario colocar não pode ser por exemplo o ano maior que 2017..o mes maior que 12

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção..

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
String dataDigitadaStr = editText.getText().toString(); // Ex: "04/05/2010"

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date dataDigitada= formater.parse(dataDigitadaStr); 

if(dataDigitada.getTime() >= Date.now()){
   Toast.makeText(this, "Data digitada maior que a data atual", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```